# Am getting too much recursion in vuejs project i think there is some issue in router.js file which causes recursion

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There are some kind of mistakes I'am making in router.js file. Constantly getting the same issue that too much recursion. There is some issue with the routes that I have defined. 
my router.js file

```
import Router from "vue-router";
import AuthRequired from "@/utils/AuthRequired";
import AuthNotRequired from "@/utils/AuthNotRequired";

Vue.use(Router);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "app" */ "./views/app/main/HomePage"),
    beforeEnter: AuthNotRequired,
    children: [
      {
        path: "app",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboards" */ "./views/app/main/Index"),
        beforeEnter: AuthRequired
      },
      {
        path: "chat",
        component: () =>
          import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "applications" */ "./views/app/applications/Chat"
          ),
        beforeEnter: AuthRequired
      },
      {
        path: "people/:user_id",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/main/UserProfile")
      },
      {
        path: "app/dashboards",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboards" */ "./views/app/dashboards"),
        redirect: "app/dashboards/default",
        children: [
          {
            path: "default",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "dashboards" */ "./views/app/dashboards/Default"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "analytics",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "dashboards" */ "./views/app/dashboards/Analytics"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "ecommerce",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "dashboards" */ "./views/app/dashboards/Ecommerce"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "content",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "dashboards" */ "./views/app/dashboards/Content"
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "app/pages",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages"),
        redirect: "/app",
        children: [
          {
            path: "data-list",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages/DataList"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "thumb-list",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages/ThumbList"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "image-list",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages/ImageList"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "details",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages/Details"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "search",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages/Search")
          },
          {
            path: "mailing",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages/Mailing"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "invoice",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "./views/app/pages/Invoice"
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "app/applications",
        component: () =>
          import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "applications" */ "./views/app/applications"
          ),
        redirect: "/app",
        children: [
          {
            path: "todo",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "applications" */ "./views/app/applications/Todo"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "survey",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "applications" */ "./views/app/applications/Survey"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "survey/:id",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "applications" */ "./views/app/applications/SurveyDetail"
              ),
            props: true
          },
          {
            path: "chat",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "applications" */ "./views/app/applications/Chat"
              )
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "app/ui",
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui"),
        redirect: "/app",
        children: [
          {
            path: "alerts",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Alerts")
          },
          {
            path: "badges",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Badges")
          },
          {
            path: "buttons",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Buttons")
          },
          {
            path: "cards",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Cards")
          },
          {
            path: "carousel",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Carousel")
          },
          {
            path: "charts",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Charts")
          },
          {
            path: "collapse",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Collapse")
          },
          {
            path: "dropdowns",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Dropdowns")
          },
          {
            path: "editors",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Editors")
          },
          {
            path: "forms",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Forms")
          },
          {
            path: "form-components",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/FormComponents"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "icons",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Icons")
          },
          {
            path: "input-groups",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/InputGroups")
          },
          {
            path: "jumbotron",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Jumbotron")
          },
          {
            path: "maps",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Maps")
          },
          {
            path: "modal",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Modal")
          },
          {
            path: "navigation",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Navigation")
          },
          {
            path: "popover-tooltip",
            component: () =>
              import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/PopoverTooltip"
              )
          },
          {
            path: "sortable",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Sortable")
          },
          {
            path: "tables",
            component: () =>
              import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ "./views/app/ui/Tables")
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/error",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "error" */ "./views/Error")
  },
  {
    path: "/user",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ "./views/user"),
    beforeEnter: AuthNotRequired,
    redirect: "/user/login",
    children: [
      {
        path: "login",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ "./views/user/Login")
      },
      {
        path: "register",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ "./views/user/Register")
      },
      {
        path: "forgot-password",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ "./views/user/ForgotPassword")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "error" */ "./views/Error")
  }
];

const router = new Router({
  linkActiveClass: "active",
  routes,
  mode: "history"
});

export default router;
```

and here is too much recursion error section.

[image]
Here is the output of browser.
[image: This is broswer snap]

Comment: will be grateful for helping me

Comment: how do you export your components? default export or named export?

Comment: am using default exports for exporting components

Comment: it was resolved there is looping redirect paths that were causing recursion

Comment: How? I'm having the same problem, my login page: this.$router.push('/register')